# I am not able to reduce the size of the Google Maps Component made by google-maps-react in my React application

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-react

Styles under the `Map` component are reducing the size of the map embedded inside the component but not the actual component itself. This will be more clear in the screenshot. I intentionally wrote `style={{ width: '10%', height: '10%'}}` to show that even if I reduce the size by a lot, the component still remains at the same size.

Code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Map, GoogleApiWrapper, Marker } from 'google-maps-react';
var config = require("../config/config").default();
export class GoogleMap2 extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
  
      this.state = {
        stores: [{lat: 47.49855629475769, lng: -122.14184416996333},
                {latitude: 47.359423, longitude: -122.021071},
                {latitude: 47.2052192687988, longitude: -121.988426208496},
                {latitude: 47.6307081, longitude: -122.1434325},
                {latitude: 47.3084488, longitude: -122.2140121},
                {latitude: 47.5524695, longitude: -122.0425407}]
      }
    }

    displayMarkers = () => {
      return this.state.stores.map((store, index) => {
        return <Marker key={index} id={index} position={{
         lat: store.latitude,
         lng: store.longitude
       }}
       onClick={() => console.log("You clicked me!")} />
      })
    }
  
    render() {
      return (
          <Map
            google={this.props.google}
            zoom={8}
            style={{ width: '10%', height: '10%'}}
            initialCenter={{ lat: 47.444, lng: -122.176}}
          >
            {this.displayMarkers()}
          </Map>
      );
    }
  }

export default GoogleApiWrapper({
    apiKey: config.apiKey,
    signature: config.signature
})(GoogleMap2)
```

Screenshot:
[image]

As you can see that the component is still having the `height: 100%` and `width: 100%` even though I reduced the size of the `Map` using the `style` attribute.
Please help me out in the actual reducing of its size.

Comment: 10% of what? Does the parent element(s) have a set width and height?

Comment: Also, from the first page of the docs, I can see the component takes a `containerStyle` property. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a property of `Map` component named `containerStyle`, commonly when you want to change from the default of position "absolute". This will take care of the `Map` container. Change the styles accordingly.

Here is the new `Map` component:

```
<Map
            google={this.props.google}
            zoom={8}
            style={{ width: '10%', height: '10%'}}
            containerStyle={{width: "40%", height: "29%", position: "fixed"}}
            initialCenter={{ lat: 47.444, lng: -122.176}}
          >
            {this.displayMarkers()}
</Map>
```